# What should be done about answers providing links to software on questions that ask for software?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I know that questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248839/any-suitable-web-based-python-editor) are off-topic and should be closed, but often I encounter their answers in the low-quality review queue.

The answers *are* answers to that question (the question asks for software links; the answers give them).  If the answers are deleted, then what is the point of keeping these questions rather than flat out deleting them?

When I encounter such answers, I flag the question for closure.  Is that the proper action?

My main question is how to treat the ***answers*** to these questions in review.  Should I say "Looks OK"?  Should I recommend deletion?

Comment: _"My main question is how to treat these answers in review. "_ If these are link only, I'd just recommend to close them. Anyway the question itself should be closed as OT.

Comment: Since IMHO the question is the main problem I often vote to close the question, add a comment to the NAA in which I ask the reviewers to take a look on the question too, and skip them hoping to get more close votes on the question. This should, however be against the general practice to vote for closing.

Comment: Well, of course the question should be deleted.   But there is protocol involved that cannot be skipped. It can never be wrong, oy vey if that produces nasty emails into SE employee in-boxes or i'm-mad-as-hell-and-you-all-suck posts in meta.  So it has to take at least 5 times more effort than what the OP put into it.  That takes time.  Just voting to close produces a lot less drama.

Comment: Treat each as an isolated incident. Mark as 'link only answer'. And whilst you're at it, flag or VTC the question for being 'off topic'.

Comment: Why are such questions off-topic?

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek I can't find the exact meta post for it yet, but the main issue is that unless the post is continually kept up to date, it becomes out of date quickly, and also easily attracts spam.

Answer (score 5):

I would say, first (vote to) close the question, because it is blatantly off-topic and is the actual cause of the problem.

For the answer, I would treat it as any other answer. If it is just a link, I would flag is as NAA - link-only. But if user has put some analysis in it, I would leave it. If the question is later deleted, the answer will go away too anyway (*).

I know we should not allow that kind of questions, and also know why : because they attract bad quality answers. But as soon as the question is closed, it won't get any more (bad ...) answer.

(*) Of course it the answer gets a positive vote, OP won't be able to delete its question. But IMHO, the problem of global deletion is for the VLQ queue, where the decision will be taken regarding the quality of the question and of (still undeleted) answers.